# Restsharp response always empty

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, restsharp

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. It is supposed to be pretty basic. The server returns JSON and I'm sending it a username and a password

```
var email = emailLoginTextBox.Text;
var password = passwordLoginTextBox.Password;
var client = new RestClient("http://www.mywebsite.com");
var request = new RestRequest("signin", Method.POST);

request.AddParameter("em", email);
request.AddParameter("pw", password);
var result = "";

client.ExecuteAsync(request, (response) =>
                                             {
                                                 result = response.Content;
                                             }
                );
Console.Write(result);
```

The executeAsync call seems to do nothing at all. The result always stays empty.
I'm using the latest Restsharp installed via Nuget.
Also in Fiddler, there is no traffic when the executeAsync is called. Is this normal?

Comment: 6 days ago there was a fix in ExecuteAsync method https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/commit/2ce5204ff97353ca44e9809ec0fb0a1e124229aa, try to get code from sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your request is async. Console.WriteLine is executed before the callback.

Try this

```
var email = emailLoginTextBox.Text;
var password = passwordLoginTextBox.Password;
var client = new RestClient("http://www.mywebsite.com");
var request = new RestRequest("signin", Method.POST);

request.AddParameter("em", email);
request.AddParameter("pw", password);
var result = "";

client.ExecuteAsync(request, (response) =>
    {
        result = response.Content;
        Console.Write(result);
    }
);
```